# Laravel access relationship models in factories

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working inside a Laravel 9 project and am using model factories. I have `User` which can have one `Company`.

I need the `CompanyFactory` details to be linked to the `User`, such as the first name and last name. The `user_id` is already mapped with Laravel.

This is my attempt, or what I thought I could do within the `CompanyFactory`:

```php
$this->user->first_name
```

Which is undefined?

Here's my seeder:

```php
// development seeders
User::factory(2)
    ->has(Affiliate::factory()->count(50))
    ->has(Company::factory()->count(1))
    ->has(Country::factory()->count(3))
    ->create();
```

And my `CompanyFactory`

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Country;
use App\Models\Company;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class CompanyFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Company::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        Log::debug('user', [
            'user' => $this->user,
        ]);

        return [
            'contact_first_name' => $user->first_name,
            'contact_last_name' => $user->last_name ? $user->last_name : null,
            'company_name' => $this->faker->company(),
            'address_1' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1, 16),
            'address_2' => 'Heatherbell Cottages',
            'address_3' => null,
            'town' => 'Wick',
            'county' => 'Caithness',
            'postcode' => 'KW14YT',
            'telephone_1' => $this->faker->regexify('07[1-57-9]{1}[0-9]{8}'),
            'telephone_2' => $this->faker->regexify('07[1-57-9]{1}[0-9]{8}'),
            'email' => $user->email,
            'bank_name' => $this->faker->word(),
            'bank_account_number' => $this->faker->numberBetween(11111111, 99999999),
            'bank_sort_code' => $this->faker->numberBetween(111111, 999999),
            'bank_iban' => $country ? $this->faker->iban($country->country_code) : null,
            'bank_swift' => '',
            'ccl_number' => null,
            'data_protection_number' => $this->faker->numberBetween(11111111, 99999999),
            'currency' => $country ? $country->currency_code : 'GBP',
            'notes' => ''
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have a `belongsTo` relation in the `Company` model.

You can use code like this.

```
$company = Company::factory()
            ->for(User::factory()->state([
                'name' => 'User name',
            ]))
            ->create();
```

OR

```
$user = User::factory()->create();
 
$company = Company::factory()
            ->for($user)
            ->create();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-factories#belongs-to-relationships

Comment: I've gone with the second approach, and a foreach loop on users. How could I associate the `->for()` with multiple column id's? For instance, a `User` can have one `Company`, but I have an affiliate model that has a `user_id` and `company_id`. I might open another Stackoverflow for further discussion.

Comment: so you want multiple companies for the same user?

Comment: A user can have one company. An affiliate is created by a user that has a company. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75106689/laravel-model-factory-seeder-assigning-two-models-to-a-model

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with using seeders for my application.

```
$companies = CompanySettings::factory()->count($this->companiesToCreate)->create();

        $companies->each(function ($company) {

            // Add Primary User
            $users = User::factory([
                'company_id' => $company->id,
                'account_status' => 1,
                'paid' => true,
                'subscriber' => true,
                'role' => 'Primary Account',
                'account_type' => 1
            ])->has(
                GlobalSettings::factory([
                    'company_id' => $company->id
                ])->count(1), 'globalSettings'
            )->count(1)->create();


        });
```