# Laravel model factory seeder assigning two models to a model

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a Laravel 9 project and need to create mass amounts of test data. I have a few models and I'd like to link them up automatically via my model factories, here's my model relationships:

- `User`
- `Company` - a user can have one company, but they might not have one.
- `Affiliate` - an affiliate has a `user_id` column, and a nullable `company_id` column, thus a user that owns a company and created an affiliate would populate both these columns.

Right now, this is how I'm linking up the `user_id` of my models:

```php
$users = User::factory(10)->create();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    Company::factory()->count(1)->for($user)->create();
    Country::factory()->count(10)->for($user)->create();
    Affiliate::factory()->count(25)->for($user)->create();
}
```

Would I need to create another `->for()` on all of the models after the `Company` so it would look something like:

```php
$users = User::factory(10)->create();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $company = Company::factory()->count(1)->for($user)->create();

    Country::factory()->count(10)->for($user)->for($company)->create();
    Affiliate::factory()->count(25)->for($user)->for($company)->create();
}
```

So that the company and user are associated to my `Affiliate`?

Comment: Does it not work as expected? If so, what exactly? Is it a general optimization question? Can’t quite figure out the question being asked :)